# Incorrect automatic baud rate detection UART LIN mode STM32G30

Tags: uart

With a preset baud rate of 19200, UART in LIN mode works fine, but the baud rate of the master node is not always known, so there is a need for automatic baud rate detection.
If the UART is set to automatic baud rate detection, then the data transfer rate is determined incorrectly, what could be the reason for this, what am I doing wrong?
Master node baud rate of 19200

UART initialization code

```
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_AUTOBAUDRATE_INIT;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AutoBaudRateEnable = UART_ADVFEATURE_AUTOBAUDRATE_ENABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AutoBaudRateMode = UART_ADVFEATURE_AUTOBAUDRATE_ONSTARTBIT;
  if (HAL_LIN_Init(&huart1, UART_LINBREAKDETECTLENGTH_11B) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
   printf("StartBaudrate = %d \n", huart1.Instance->BRR);
   
   while(__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1,UART_FLAG_REACK) == RESET){}
   while(__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1,UART_FLAG_TEACK) == RESET){}
   while(__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1,UART_FLAG_ABRF) == RESET){}
   if (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1, UART_FLAG_ABRE)!= RESET)
   {
    Error_Handler();
   }
    else
        {
      while(__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1,UART_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET){}
          }
    printf("NowBaudrate = %d \n", huart1.Instance->BRR);
}
```

UART_Init_LOG

```
SystemCoreClock: 64000000 
StartBaudrate = 115107, Instance->BRR = 556
NowBaudrate = 1484, Instance->BRR = 43102 
UART Status Flags
UART_FLAG_TXFT: 0 
UART_FLAG_RXFT: 0 
UART_FLAG_RXFF: 0 
UART_FLAG_TXFE: 0 
UART_FLAG_REACK: 1 
UART_FLAG_TEACK: 1 
UART_FLAG_WUF: 0 
UART_FLAG_RWU: 0 
UART_FLAG_SBKF: 0 
UART_FLAG_CMF: 0 
UART_FLAG_BUSY: 0 
UART_FLAG_ABRF: 1 
UART_FLAG_ABRE: 0 
UART_FLAG_RTOF: 0 
UART_FLAG_CTS: 0 
UART_FLAG_CTSIF: 0 
UART_FLAG_LBDF: 0 
UART_FLAG_TXE: 1 
UART_FLAG_TXFNF: 1 
UART_FLAG_TC: 1 
UART_FLAG_RXNE: 1 
UART_FLAG_RXFNE: 1 
UART_FLAG_IDLE: 1 
UART_FLAG_ORE: 1 
UART_FLAG_NE: 1 
UART_FLAG_FE: 0 
UART_FLAG_PE: 0
```

Comment: "*Automatic baud rate detection*" only works reliably if the sender transmits a known pattern, e.g. a steady stream of a single character.  IOW both ends of the link must be aware of this detection is in progress.

Comment: @sawdust, not only. The hardware may count the length of the bits. There is a hardware assisted protocol, but the problem is that in most of the hardware it works only for _standard_ baud rates (from the table) and up to 115200, which is not high speed.